# Forcing entry of certain character types in UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

If I have a UITextField which the user is inputing a registration number, which has the format:
11-11-1111

(that is 2 digits, a dash, 2 digits, a dash, four digits)

How do I force the user to enter this kind of data only (as they are actually entering it)... so they can't enter anything except 0-9 in the first character, and only '-' for the third character etc.

Answer (score 2):

From a UX point of view, since the '-' characters are fixed, limit the input to just 0-9 by setting the `keyboardType` property of `UITextField` to `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`.

Implement `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol's `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method and check the length of the `textField.text` and append the '-' character automatically when the length is 2 or 5. When the length reaches 10 characters, do not accept any new characters, just deletes.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the input with a regex and show an error message, if it's in the wrong format. See [here](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/). Or you can split the string at the dashes and look at the parts (convert them to integer, for example) (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:)).

Another (untested and theoretical) approach would be: set the textfield delegate to your controller:

```
myTextField.delegate = self
```

and then try:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];
return ([string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0);
}
```

Comment: I would rather not show an error. I want to actually limit what they can enter, as they are entering it.

Answer (score 0):

ok figured it out from another post

use

```
   if (range.length != 1){
            NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]; 
            returnValue = ([string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0);
        }
```